# double for loop in R giving irrelevant output

Tags: r

I have a data which I am trying to aggregate using double for loop. Basically, I want to calculate Purchase cycle for each MEM_ID by each TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY. Data is shown as below,

```
MEM_ID  ORDER_DEL_DATE  TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY
999984  2016-01-07         household
999984  2016-02-03         household
999980  2015-12-16         household
999980  2016-01-03         household
999980  2016-01-05         household
999980  2016-02-14         household
999984  2016-01-07         personal-care
999980  2016-01-03         personal-care
999980  2016-01-30         personal-care
```

The code

```
PC_test <- NA
for(i in unique(test$MEM_ID)){
  for(j in unique(test$TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY)){
    PC_test[c(i,j)] <- data.frame(c(MEM_ID=i,CATEGORY=j,ifelse(nrow(test[test$MEM_ID==i & test$TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY==j,])<=2, 
                 max(test[test$MEM_ID==i & test$TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY==j,"ORDER_DEL_DATE"])-min(test[test$MEM_ID==i & test$TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY==j,"ORDER_DEL_DATE"]),
                  max(test[test$MEM_ID==i & test$TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY==j,"ORDER_DEL_DATE"])-maxN(test[test$MEM_ID==i & test$TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY==j,"ORDER_DEL_DATE"]))))
  }
}
```

Note: maxN function gives the second largest.

throwing an irrelevant output as below,

```
NA. X999984    household    personal.care   X999980
NA       999984      999980      999980         999980
NA   personal-care  household   personal-care   personal-care
NA    0               40           27                27
```

I expecting the output in below format,

```
 MEM_ID       TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY   PC_test
 999984           household          27
 999984           personal-care      0
 999980           household          40
 999980           personal-care      27
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You may not need a `for` loop (functions like `by` and `aggregate` may be helpful). __please add an explanation for how "purchase cycle" is calculated in your question__

Comment: @bouncyball, Purchase Cycle is the difference between when was a particular customer made his last purchase from previous last purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
require(data.table)

setDT(df1)

#  calculate the min and max date for each MEM_ID/TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY pair, then find the difference for PC_test
df1[,  .(max_date=max(ORDER_DEL_DATE), min_date=min(ORDER_DEL_DATE)),
  keyby=.(MEM_ID,TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY)][, .(MEM_ID, TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY, PC_test = max_date - min_date)]


   MEM_ID TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY PC_test
1: 999980          household 60 days
2: 999980      personal-care 27 days
3: 999984          household 27 days
4: 999984      personal-care  0 days
```

Based on what you said, this is my educated guess on how you're calculating PC_test without totally breaking apart your min and max formulas.

Comment: @Frank you lose Category if you do it like that. You still get the right day numbers for PC_test though

Comment: @Frank It's a good point avoiding the duplicates, I updated my solution to reflect your input.

Comment: Ok, side note: this way is good because it is efficient (see `?GForce`), but `df1[, .(PC_test = max(ORDER_DEL_DATE) - min(ORDER_DEL_DATE)), keyby=.(MEM_ID, TOP_LEVEL_CATEGORY)]` should also work, I guess.